# How to a convert a domestic gas C.H. Boiler to use Hydrogen?

Tags: heating-systems, gas, natural-gas

What engineering changes are needed to convert a domestic gas boiler from running on natural gas (i.e. north sea gas) to hydrogen?

The UK government is currently planning on switching to using hydrogen gas by the end of the decade.

One of my memories as a small child was our antique gas boiler being converted from town gas (aka coal gas) to natural gas. This involved changing the sizes of holes in the burner, and took an hour or two. However, as far as I can tell this isn't the case for converting to hydrogen.

According to [this government document](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/media/5c000b2040f0b65b05165948/hydrogen-logistics.pdf) (section 5.1 page 28) each UK boiler will take up to a day to convert to hydrogen. (this is in addition to updating the supply pipework).

What physical, engineering changes are required to convert a boiler to hydrogen?

Comment: Also says 1 day to convert a boiler on page 4... didn't have to read far. As for exactly what - that will depend on many factors individual to each boiler as materials used differ. different materials were mentioned on page 3...

Comment: the hydrogen molecule is one of the smallest possible, so it is able to pass through the smallest of holes and even pass through some solids ... the whole system has to be retrofitted to prevent leaks ... a natural gas system would probably leak hydrogen like a sieve